# C++ Difference between Pointer and &Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

So I am kinda new to C++ and I have following code:

```
DWORD64 dwPointer = 0;

long test1 = dwPointer;     //equals 0
LPVOID test2 = (LPVOID)dwPointer;  //equals 0x0000000000000000
LPVOID test3 = &dwPointer; //equals 0x000000a5038ff068 (result changes after each restart)
```

So If I debug it test1 & test2 both basically equals 0.
But why does the value of test3 change everytime I restart the program.
What does the & infront of the Pointer do?

Also Is it possible to replicate the exact same example in C#? Which code would I have to use, I just want to understand whats happening since I am a C# user and I am wondering how a predefined DWORD64 = 0 value can change to different Values after each restart even tho nothing assigns those new values in code?

Comment: `dwPointer` is a `DWORD64` (which is generally `unsigned long` in the window API, IIRC) with value zero.   `(LPVOID)dwPointer` converts that zero value to a pointer, so produces a null pointer.   `&dwPointer` is the address in memory of `dwPointer` i.e. variable has value zero, and an address in memory (which will not be zero).     Your code is not changing the value of `dwPointer`, and that doesn't change when after "restart".   The address of that variable, however, depends on how the operating system allocates memory to the process.

Comment: _"Also Is it possible to replicate the exact same example in C#?"_ No.

Comment: *"how a predefined DWORD64 = 0 value can change to different Values"* -- it doesn't, as you demonstrated. Each time you used your `DWORD64` value (called `dwPointer`), the value was zero. The time you got something different was when you applied an operator to `dwPointer`, specifically the `&` operator. The point of most operators is to transform one value into something else, so it should be no surprise that `operator&` produced a value other than `dwPointer`. (The fact that the resulting value changes with each restart could be surprising, but not the fact that the result is not zero.)

Comment: In c# you can use Marshaling classes for handling un-managed memory.

Answer (score 0):

`&dwPointer` get dwPointer's own address (a new pointer points to dwPointer's location).